# Putting code in a text box (MS Access)

Tags: ms-access

I am using a textbox for the header of my report, and based on what the user selects it will be "Baseline 8", "Baseline 9", etc. What I would like to do is have the text box coded so whatever number the user selects is entered into the text box. I managed to do it by using two text boxes, one just says "baseline" and the other text box says "=[Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform]![Combo21]" and it will enter the correct value. But what I want to do is put it all in one box, and when I put "Baseline =[Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform]![Combo21]" in the text box it doesn't work, it just leaves the code as the header when I generate the report. Is there something I'm not doing correctly?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, when you state that a "textbox says", you really mean that "the Control Source property of the textbox equals."  For a textbox (and some other controls), the value that you see on the actual form IS the Control Source property.  I am not being picky for its own sake, rather it is important to recognize what value you are editing.

The Control Source property can essentially contain two types of values.  The first is without an equals sign and it indicates the name of a field from the form Record Source.  In that case, it binds the control to the field directly so that it automatically loads from the field and saves changes back to the field.

The second type of value always starts with `=`.  It is a VBA code expression and can include calls to functions and other VBA operators.  In your case, you want to concatenate (i.e. combine) two strings: one literal `"Baseline"` and one pulled from an access object `[Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform]![Combo21]`, so you need to use the string concatenation operator `&`.

```
 ="Baseline " & [Forms]![Navigation Form]![NavigationSubform]![Combo21]
```